# C# Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, types

I am a bit confused on why isn't this code running through. This is only a small portion of the code, but everything works besides the part of the code where I try to:

return item.priceUsd and  return "No Price Found", That I am trying to assign to a variable string coin_price

```
public class Exchange
{
    public string exchangeId { get; set; }
    public string baseId { get; set; }
    public string quoteId { get; set; }
    public string baseSymbol { get; set; }
    public string quoteSymbol { get; set; }
    public string volumeUsd24Hr { get; set; }
    public string priceUsd { get; set; }
    public string volumePercent { get; set; }
}

public class Exchanges
{
    public List<Exchange> data { get; set; }
}

public static Exchanges GetPrice(string coin_name, string exchange_name)
    {
        using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient())
        {
            
            string response = Client.GetStringAsync(base_URL + "assets/" + coin_name + "/markets").Result;
            Exchanges list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exchanges>(response);
            
            foreach(var item in list.data)
            { 
                if(item.exchangeId == exchange_name)
                {
                    return item.priceUsd;
                }

            }

            return "No Price Found";
        }
        
    }
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
       
        string coin_price = Method.GetPrice(name, ename);
        
        //Console.WriteLine(coin_price);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I keep getting the " Cannot implicitly convert type " error. But I've made sure the type of "item.priceUsd" is a string and I am trying to return it and assign to another string "coin_price".

What am I missing here?

Comment: The function declaration states it will return an `Exchanges`, not a `string`. Did you mean: `public static string GetPrice(string coin_name, string exchange_name)`?

Comment: You are not returning an `item` of type `Exchanges` but a `priceUsd` of type `string`. But are you sure that you want to store prices, percents and IDs as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the **main issue** I see is that the method needs to **return the class type** `Exchanges` **and you are returning a** `string`

C# is **type-safe,** meaning that when you declare a new method and tell it that the **return value** is supposed to be a `string`, **the method body needs to return a** `string`.

so that is why it is returning the error `Can't implicitly convert type`.

Since you are returning strings, either way, try to change the methods return type to string.

**Like this:**

```
public static string GetPrice(string coin_name, string exchange_name){
  //your code here.
}
```

If you want to return another type, you need to change the return values so that it returns the type the method needs.